# Fork remote SVN repo to git

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

Apologies if this question is a duplicate, or if I've missed something, but in all my searching of the interwebz, I can't find any information on this.

I want to fork someone else's SVN project, and then turn it into a local git repo (hopefully preserving all of the SVN commits).  All the examples I've found have only talked about how to turn **your own** SVN repo into a git repo via `git svn`.

For example, I occasionally write some Adobe AIR apps, and I like to use the open-source [AlivePDF](http://code.google.com/p/alivepdf/source/checkout) library for PDF generation.  The SVN repo URL is `http://alivepdf.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/`.  Since I have made some changes to the source code that I use locally in my PDF generation, I want to then turn my local fork into a git project.  I've tried to just do `git svn clone http://alivepdf.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ alivepdf-read-only --no-metadata --stdlayout .` (from the directory where I want to store it).  However when I look at the git repo history (`gitx` on Mac), it appears to be empty, i.e., no history of the original AlivePDF author's commits.

Am I doing something wrong?  Do I need to SVN fork the project first, *then* change it into a git project?  Please advise.

Comment: you should either use `http://alivepdf.googlecode.com/svn/` with --stdlayout or `http://alivepdf.googlecode.com/svn/trunk` without --stdlayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running 
`git svn clone http://alivepdf.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ alivepdf-read-only` on my machine works as expected and gives me complete history, eg:

```
nexus-Tablet8\nexus C:\Users\nexus\Development\Misc\alivepdf-read-only
[master]# git log --oneline -3
c3b93fb Add the test case reported by the user in the issue 338.
3577380  - now set the unit to the unit of the new page in addPage.  - add *MarginPt to keep the values in pixel, the olc
08653f Add a test case to test issue 340.
```

Are you seeing something different?

(I tried making this a comment on your question insteadof an answer, but the formatting gets messed up)

Comment: Hmm, that seemed stupidly easy.  I got the `--no-metadata --stdlayout` from some other tutorial I was trying to follow.  Doing it this way worked fine.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361559/what-does-the-stdlayout-do-in-git-svn-clone for more info on what exactly `--stdlayout` does. The repo you wanted to clone has no branches and I made the assumption that the tags weren't really important in your case.