# git svn: No remote branches after cloning

Tags: git, svn, git-clone

I am trying to use git-svn for a svn repository. Unfortunatelly I can't seem to get it work.

As I clone the repository

```
git svn clone https://svn.tugraz.at/svn/reponame
```

I get the message that an empty git repository has been initialized:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/snooc/workspace/reponame/.git/
```

and

```
git branch -a
```

also just gives me

```
*master
```

These are my configs:

```
user.name=Stefan Falk
user.email=<a-valid-email-address>
push.default=simple
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
svn-remote.svn.url=https://svn.tugraz.at/svn/reponame
svn-remote.svn.fetch=:refs/remotes/git-svn
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You should've used --stdlayout option of git svn clone.
This option makes git treat trunk, branches, and tags folders in a special way.
Without it, git just mirrors naturally flat structure of svn repository.

[What does the --stdlayout do in git svn clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361559/what-does-the-stdlayout-do-in-git-svn-clone)